# Printing coefficients of a multiple linear regression / TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-regression, coefficients

I have a multiple linear regression and want to print the coefficients:

```
predictors = ['A', 'B', 'c']
outcome = ['Y']

sales_data_lm = LinearRegression()
sales_data_lm.fit(sales_data[predictors], sales_data[outcome])

print(f'Intercept: {sales_data_lm.intercept_:.4f}')
print('Coefficients:')
for name, coef in zip(predictors, sales_data_lm.coef):
    print(f'{name}: {coef}')
```

I am getting a type error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1104/3766417539.py in <module>
 13 sales_data_lm.fit(house_sales[predictors], sales_data[outcome])
 14 
 ---> 15 print(f'Intercept: {sales_data_lm.intercept_:.4f}')
 16 print('Coefficients:')
 17 for name, coef in zip(predictors, sales_data_lm.coef_):

 TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__
```

I don´t understand why this doesn´t work, and my research here and over the web have been fruitless so far. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`intercept_` is stored in a numpy array of shape `(1,)`. If you want to pass if to the string using a format specifier you need to retrieve the single element from the array:

```
print(f'Intercept: {sales_data_lm.intercept_[0]:.4f}')
```

Comment: Thanks LukasNeugebauer and MMSA. That works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
sales_data_lm = LinearRegression()
sales_data_lm.fit(df[predictors], df[outcome])

print(f'Intercept: {sales_data_lm.intercept_[0]:.4f}')
print('Coefficients:')
for name, coef in zip(predictors, sales_data_lm.coef_):
    print(f'{name}: {coef}')
```

intercept_ Stored in an array and also, you have a syntax error in coef it is coef_